# How to extract the portion of headers data from CSV file

Tags: python, csv

The CSV having larger data with multiple header's like  (Modules, Device names, Events).
My required would to pick the Events portion to calculate the port usage.

I am able to read CSV file using the below python script, but not sure how to extract events header(Source, Severity, Type, Description) portion from CSV. Could you please advice how to get the portion of data.

```
import csv

req_file = "C:\\hi\\test\Desktop\\data\\xyz.csv"

fo = open(req_file, "r")
content = csv.reader(fo, delimiter=",")
l = []
for each in content:
  l.append(each)
print(l)
fo.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a sample of your CSV, but assuming you have a CSV like the following:

```
Header1,header2
data1,data2
data3,data4
```

`next()` will read one item from the iterator and `list()` will read everything else:

```
import csv

req_file = "C:\\hi\\test\Desktop\\data\\xyz.csv"

with open(req_file, newline='') as fo:  # newline per csv docs.
    content = csv.reader(fo)            # iterator, comma is default
    header = next(content)              # header is first line read
    l = list(content)                   # create list of remaining lines.
```

and you will get:

```
header = ['Header1','Header2']
l = [['data1','data2'],['data3','data4']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The headers are like as the below.

Source,  Severity,   Type,    First Seen Time,   Last Seen Time,   Count, Description